# how to implement something like remote desktop or LogmeIn in Java?

Tags: java

how to implement something like remote desktop or LogmeIn in Java?  should I use something like Java.awt.Robot?  which libraries should I look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.awt.Robot` will be indispensable for emulating pointer and keyboard events on the controlled machine. Besides that I can suggest looking up how the VNC protocol works and

- either implement it (and some of the encoding schemes you like), so you can run any VNC viewer against your server or
- implement something which has a saner on-wire protocol, but then you'll have to roll your own viewers as well.

I can't really recommend any library to support you doing this, as it's really a niche project. I have my own library doing this, but it's closed source proprietary stuff. It's not really hard to get something up an running, good luck.